# Apache load balancing over WAN

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

We have developed a PHP application to run on Apache on Linux.

Now, customer wants a load balanced & high availability setup. For load balancing, he proposes to use CloudFlare and deploy the app on on-premises servers. So, each server would have a public IP via the firewall.

However, he wants to place each server at a different location to protect against link failures as well as complete site failures.

Can Apache be configured for HA over WAN?

If the two servers run independently of each other, how would sessions be maintained?

Comment: Apache has no native support to synchronise sessions or state. A fairly typical PHP approach is that you create a session handler that stores sessions in a database , since you probably need method to  synchronise the database anyway ...

Comment: The database is provided by client on a separate DB cluster. Re your comment on storing sessions in a DB, how is that achieved?